# jQuery Mobile trigger('create') finished on listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm rendering a listview where I want to call my function, `hideUncheckedListItems()`, once trigger('create') has finished to manipulate the listview. Is there an event I can listen for when it's finished? Or some other way of triggering the function once the listview has been created?

I've tried the following, but it seems to trigger too early:

```
this.content.trigger('create').trigger('listrendered');
```

This is in the context of a Phonegap app that uses Backbone.

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#event-create)?

Comment: @Jack No, that doesn't seem to do the trick. The function works fine if I call it from the Chrome developer console once the page is loaded, but I'm struggling to find a way to call it once the listview has finished rendering. Because it's a single page Phonegap app using Backbone I have to manually render the listview.

Comment: Perhaps a timeout would do the trick (`setTimeout( function() { ....},1)1;`).

Comment: @Jack Yes, I'll probably wind up resorting to that. It's not the best solution, but, if it does the job...